# boot windows 7 from internal ssd connected via usb

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, ssd, bsod

I have an internal SSD with a dual boot arch linux/Windows 7 grub. I bought a usb to sata adapter and plugged the usb to a toshiba laptop - the system starts to boot normally from the USB device, up to the point where the animated Windows pictogram appears (description from [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/bsod-help-support/149339-bsod-when-booting-usb-hd.html)). Then I get a bluescreen (`STOP: 0x7B`).

Safe mode, last driver loaded is `aswRvrt.sys`

Arch boots to the terminal but when I issue `startx` it fails with `Fatal server error: no screens found(EE)`

Is it hopeless ?

EDIT: this is not a duplicate of the question cited - I do not want to *install* to the usb - I want to *BOOT* from the usb. Plugging the SSD to a desktop worked out of the box.

Comment: If you don't install Windows to the drive, how would you expect to boot into Windows from it? The point is [Windows won't boot from USB](http://superuser.com/questions/62506/can-windows-7-boot-from-an-external-usb-or-firewire-drive?lq=1) without using a 3rd party utility to install/patch it.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: Windows are installed into the drive (a dual boot grub2 drive) - possibly it's a laptop (as opposed to desktop) thing - not sure that's why I asked